# I wanted to change my default Fedora bash shell to ssh (as a superuser)

Tags: fedora

I wanted to change my default Fedora bash shell to ssh (as a superuser).

So, using chsh command gave the address /bin/ssh. Logout the superuser. But after login as su, I am unable to login and getting this issue:-

**Issue**

```
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]

[-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]

[-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]

[-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]

[-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]

[-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]

[user@]hostname [command]
```

Moreover, the terminal echoes current shell as bash.

Comment: What made you want to do this?  ssh is not a login shell, it is a way to access the shell on a remote machine.

Comment: What do you mean by "_after login as su_"? You don't login as su (unless you've created a user called `su`). You might login as root, or you might login as a normal user and then run `su`. Or you might be doing something else entirely.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be talking apples and oranges. Bash, csh, zsh, etc are `shells`. Secure Shell (SSH) is a communication protocol (and program) for connecting to remote computers. SSH connects you to a shell running on a remote computer, but is not itself a shell. This is why trying to set `/bin/ssh` as your shell fails.

Comment: Technically sshd IS a ptty though and the client ssh is technically a shell that forwards all commands via the ssh protocol to a ptty on the remote machine.

Comment: The SSH client may forward commands via the SSH protocol to a ptty on a remote machine, but the SSH client is not a shell itself. A shell is run on the remote machine to actually interact with. Running the SSH client executable itself (as displayed in the question) does not start any type of shell environment without arguments. If you do add arguments to connect to a machine, then you're no longer using it as a "shell" on the existing account and machine, but to connect to either a different account on the same machine or a different machine all together.